# How to grep specific *name* in subfolders in Linux?

Tags: linux, grep, find

To grep some string in all subfolders I can use:

```
grep -rl "test" /path
```

I would like to grep some specific string assuming that the first part and the second part of the string could be different (has got different begin and end) and is case insensitive.
I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
grep -rli "*test*" /path
```

Could you please tell me how to do this?

To be clear I would like to find all files (grep) including subfolders, where there is specific string, like e.g.:

```
"*test*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try grep accepting [perl regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

```
grep -irlP ".*test.*" /path
```

The `.*` means matching (zero or more times) *any* characters except *newline*. More about meta-characters [here](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html)

You can use almost any regex, so it's a really flexible solution to match complex patterns. For instance, if you searched for entire words only:

```
grep -rlP "\b(test)\b" /path
```

Of course there are limitations. For instance, multiline search with this method can be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this using the `"--include"` option:

```
grep -rli --include="test*" /path
```

From the man page of grep

> **--include=GLOB**
>
> Search only files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard
>   matching as described under --exclude).

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -ilr "string" path/to/subdir
```

Will search sub-strings as well. grep searches pattern - you don't need those asterisks (or dot asterisks as in my pre-edit answer).

If you want to search the exact word and not its presence in sub-strings, use -w option.